# How to use cmd type pipe (/piping) in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, pipe

In cmd (and bash), pipe "`|`" pushes output to another command in the original format of the first command's output (as string).

In PowerShell, everything that comes out the pipe is an object (even a string is a string object).

Because of that, some commands fail when run in a PowerShell command window as opposed to a Windows command window.

Example:

```
dir c:\windows | gzip > test.gz
```

When this command is run in the Windows command prompt window it works properly - directory listing of C:\windows gets compressed into test.gz file.

The same command in PowerShell fails, because PowerShell does not use cmd-style pipe and replaces it with PowerShell pipe (working with array of file system items).

**Q.** How do you disable the default piping behavior in PowerShell to make traditional Windows commands work identically in PowerShell?

I tried using the escape character "`` ` ``" before the pipe "`` `| ``", but it didn't work. I also tried `invoke-expression -command "command with | here"`, but it also failed.

Comment: why would you want to circumvent this? if you're working in powershell, why not accept it's conventions?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass a file list to a zip program to zip up those files.  If that's the case, I would re-phrase your question to ask how to accomplish that in PowerShell, not how to get PowerShell to behave like DOS.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to send strings down the pipeline you can use the cmdlet "out-string"

For Example:

```
get-process | out-string
```

If you are specifically looking for a PowerShell way to zip up files, check out the PowerShell Community Extensions. there are a bunch of cmdlets to zip and unzip all kinds of files.

http://pscx.codeplex.com

Comment: Agreed on all points. Powershell's pipeline is way more powerful than the Unix/DOS-style pipeline.  Disabling it by default, even if possible, would be a Bad Idea(tm).  that Google thinks might help explain it. Generally speaking, Out-String is the command that converts the stream of objects that Powershell works with to the stream of text that Unix/DOS expects.

Answer (score 4):

If you can pipe the output of (CMD) dir into gzip, then gzip apparently knows how to parse dir output.  The (string) output from the PowerShell dir command (aka Get-ChildItem) doesn't look the same, so gzip likely would not be able to parse it.  But, I'd also guess that gzip would be happy to take a list of paths, so this would probably work:

```
dir c:\windows | select -ExpandProperty FullName | gzip > test.gz
```

No warrantees express or implied.

Comment: This is what I would suggest.  I do not think it is safe to rely on default formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use the old school DOS pipe system in PowerShell, it can be done by running a command in a separate, temporary DOS session:

```
& cmd /c "dir c:\windows | gzip > test.gz"
```

The `/c` switch tells `cmd` to run the command then exit. Of course, this only works if all the commands are old school DOS - you can't mix-n-match them with PowerShell commands.

While there are PowerShell alternatives to the example given in the question, there are lots of DOS programs that use the old pipe system and will not work in PowerShell. `svnadmin load` is one that I've the pleasure of having to deal with.

Comment: Small additions: 1) You can omit '&' symbol; 2) In case you want to use quotes inside the command you can use quote escaping: `cmd /c "dir c:\windows | gzip > \`"test archive.gz\`""`

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  PowerShell was designed to pass objects down a pipeline, not text.  There isn't a backwards-compatability mode to DOS.